# AnyLogic "null" error while importing Database Table

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to import an Excel file with 6K rows and 6 columns (only 200KB) in AnyLogic 8.8.2. However, I am receiving a "null" error while trying to import the file. Below is a screenshot of the error:

[AnyLogic Null Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5jxj.png)

I even manually created a fresh test file with 5 column headers and 5K rows (below), however, I still ran into the same error. When I reduce the number of records to around 1K, the file easily gets imported. Is there any limitation on database table size while importing in AnyLogic?

[Test Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNguT.png)

Comment: There is no limit. Ensure your rows below the last data row are 100% clean (best delete them manually). Maybe AnyLogic cannot "see" the end of the sheet as there is some dirty stuff happening?

Comment: @Benjamin, thanks for your response. I manually deleted the rows as well, however unfortunately, it still doesn't work. For similar reason, I created a test file to ensure it is 100% clean, but does not work.

Comment: feel free to share the test file, I can see if it works for me :)

Comment: I've run into this more times than I can count... some files will refuse to cooperate, no manner how much you try to clean them. Your file is small, so if you don't need to have it automatically update from your source, you can workaround this by manually copy-pasting your data into an empty AnyLogic DB.

Comment: @Benjamin, here is the link to the test file: https://github.com/sukhmanimarwah/Test-Files/blob/main/test.xlsx

Comment: @Shingston, I am facing the same issue with every Excel file of similar size or beyond. I loaded the same table using MS Access and it finally got imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loks like this was a bug in v8.8.2, should now be fixed in 8.8.3:
[image]